# Regular expression for a password containing at least 1 upper and lowercase letters, 1 number and 1 special charater with minimum length of 8

Tags: javascript, angular

This is not working in Angular 7 as validation passes without an uppercase letter.

```
password: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=[^\\W]*\\W)([a-zA-Z0-9\\W]+)$'), Validators.minLength(8)]],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, You can change your regex to

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\W).{8,}$
```

[image]

```js
let strArr = ["123456789","1aA12345@","abcdefghi","@@@@1!!!!"]

strArr.forEach(str=>{
  console.log(str, /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\W).{8,}$/.test(str))
})
```

Comment: this works, thanks, what tool did you use for the GUI though :)

Comment: @zeddysoft glad to hear that, this is called [`Regex visualizer`](https://jex.im/regulex/)

Answer (score 0):

Once try this RegExp

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}/
```